# C++ (long* lpHandle) conversion to C#

Tags: c#, pointers, visual-c++, pinvoke, handle

Hi I have a 2 methods in a C++ MFC which calls both `long* lpHandle` and `long lHandle` respectively. I would like to convert these calls to C#.

C++ MFC example:

```
//The api methods
NETCLIENT_API int   API_CALL    NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig(long* lpHandle);

NETCLIENT_API int   API_CALL    NETCLIENT_MCConfig(const char* szDevIDNO, int nType, 
GPSConfigData_S* pConfig, void* pUsr, void (CALLBACK * FUNMCMsgCB)(GPSMCMsg_S* pMsg, void* pUsr)
, long lHandle);

...
... 

    CDlgTransParam::CDlgTransParam(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CDlgTransParam::IDD, pParent)
{
    //set handle to null
    m_lParamHandle = NULL;
}

...
... 

void CDlgTransParam::DoConfig(CString strIDNO, int nType, GPSConfigData_S* lpInConfig)
{
    //opens config handle
    NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig(&m_lParamHandle);
    // Sends message; //m_lParamHandle is the return handle of NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig
    NETCLIENT_MCConfig(strIDNO, nType, lpInConfig, this, FUNGetDevConfig, m_lParamHandle);
}
```

The C# Winform conversion I have been working on:

```
//Delegate methods
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void FUNMCMsgCB(int nMsg, Form1 form1);

class NETCLASS
{
//--
[DllImport("libnetclient.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig(_x);
//--
[DllImport("libnetclient.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int NETCLIENT_MCConfig(string szDevIDNO, int nType,
string pConfig, Form1 form1, FUNMCMsgCB _callback, _x);
}

...
...

 private void Sendbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //opens config handle
  int handle = NETCLASS.NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig(_x);
  // Sends message; //m_lParamHandle is the return handle of NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig
  FUNMCMsgCB _callback = new FUNMCMsgCB(FUNMCMsgCB);
  int param3 = NETCLASS.NETCLIENT_MCConfig(szDevIDNO,  0, pdata, this,  _callback, _x);
}
```

In the C# example you will see `_x`. according to the [DOC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9714/Win32-API-C-to-NET). C++ `long` is converted to `int` in C#.
I tried defining this like:

```
        int str = 0;//set value to zero
        GCHandle handlel = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Weak);//handle type
        IntPtr pointer = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handlel);//define pointer
        int lHandle = pointer.ToInt32();//convert to int
```

It did not work. I also noticed that the variable name of the `long` type is lpHandle as stated in the api method (`e.g "long* lpHandle"`). Which is `Intptr` in C# so naturally I tried using `Intptr` and `ref Intptr` like :

```
NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig(ref IntPtr lHandle);//ref pointer
NETCLIENT_MCOpenConfig(IntPtr lHandle);//normal pointer
```

Still no luck. If anyone has any suggestions or tips I'll greatly appreciate it thanks.

Comment: A handle is a number not a pointer.  Since a IntPtr is 32 bits and a int handle is 32 bits either will work in a 32 bit system.  Many examples use IntPtr.  I usually use an uint since it is more correct.  In a 64 bit system you may need to allocate a long so the code works properly.  It depends if the library libnetclient.dll was built as a 32 bit application or a 64 bit application.

Comment: It should work... I think the problem is how are you handling the callback struct. Also remember to use `ref IntPtr lHandle` on the correct function which requires a reference.